# Getting the full list from a HTML Datalist clicking on the arrow

Tags: html, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete, datalist

If a item is selected it is not possible to see the full list by cliking the arrow  as shown in the diagram.

```
    <div>    
    <input type="text"  id="client" list="allclients"  placeholder="Start typing..." value="" />
    <datalist id="allclients">
        <select>
            <option value="Jack">Jack</option>
            <option value="John">John</option>
        </select>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

[image]

If the user select one he cannot see the full list unless input is cleared again. Is there a way to get rid of this limitaion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior and what I asked is not possible. The list supposed to get filter by the user input text.

Possible solutions for this issue can be solved using one of these

http://pebbleroad.github.io/combo-select/

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox